# angular-meteor "Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor, collections, angular-meteor

I'm runing this app under cloud9 IDE. Meteor 1.3.2.4

meteor list:

angular                1.3.10
autopublish            1.0.7
es5-shim               4.5.10
insecure               1.0.7
jquery                 1.11.8 
meteor-base            1.0.4
mobile-experience      1.0.4
mongo                  1.1.7
reactive-var           1.0.9
standard-minifier-css  1.0.6
tracker                1.0.13

my ./client/main.html

```
<head>
  <title>Joakenpo</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="joakenpo">
  <h1>Joakenpo</h1>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="person in list">{{person.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

My ./server/main.js

```
List = new Mongo.Collection('list');

Meteor.startup(() => {
    console.log('Joakenpo running');
    ['John', 'Peter', 'Rachel'].map((name) => List.insert({ name: name }));
    console.log(List.find().count());
});
```

my ./client/main.js

```
angular
  .module('joakenpo', ['angular-meteor'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ($log, $scope) => {
    $log.debug('main controller');
    $scope.message = 'Module running';
    $scope.helpers({
      list() {
        return Meteor.List.find({});
      }
    });
  })
  .run(($log) => $log.debug('Joakenpo Module Running'));
```

My error

angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:12535
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935140/has-importing-collections-changed-in-meteor-1-4-0-1

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your `List` collection in common code, not just in server.js. Also you can't refer to it as `Meteor.List`, and you'll also need to import it.

This tutorial shows how to do all that properly: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/collections

Comment: Ok, finally it works! I've created a new folder ./lib in which I saved a main.js file with just one line **"List = new Mongo. Collection ('list');"**! In the client main.js I switched the $scope.helpers for **"$scope. list = $meteor.collection (List)"**. _Thank you very much indeed_.